# AWS Glue Python MemoryError

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have files in S3 that are checked with a Python script in AWS Glue. For each file I check the first line to see if the format is correct and then I register a row in Redshift in case of error and I move the file path in the same S3 bucket.

The code keeps running for each file until it raises an error of MemoryError. I use Maximum capacity = 1 for the  Glue job and the files are no bigger than 200MB. If I monitor the memory usage it keeps increasing until a given point, then it keeps processing files until the error raises. Do you know what can be happening?

```
for key in get_matching_s3_keys("bucket", "", "x/x5d",""):
    print (key)
    print (resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss)

    if( (key.split("/")[2] != "")):

        obj = s3.Object('bucket',key)
        filedata = obj.get()['Body'].read()
        gzipfile = BytesIO(filedata)
        
        file = key.split("/")[-1]#.split(".")[0]
        print(file) 
       
        try: 
            content = gzipfile.read()
        except ValueError:
            print ("read error!")    
        
        print("content")
        #print (type(content)) 
        fl = str(content).split("\n")[0]
        #print (fl)
        print("split")

        tf = file.split("_")[0] 
        cd = file.split("_")[1]
        cc = file.split("_")[2]
        da = file.split("_")[3].split(".")[0]
        ve = key.split("/")[-1].split(".")[1]
    
        tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')
        dc = datetime.datetime.now(tz).strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
        st = 1

 if ";" not in fl:
            de = "error is X"
            res2 = con1.query("INSERT INTO table (x,y,z,zz,zzz,zzzz,yy,yyy,yyyy) VALUES ('"+file+"','"+tf+"','"+cd+"','"+cc+"','"+da+"','"+str(ve)+"','"+dc+"','"+str(st)+"','"+de+"')") 
    
            
            #print ("; error!")
            ##fil a file and store it in S3 under 
            client = key.split("/")[0]

            
            keydes = client+"/x/y/x5d/"+"O_"+file
            #print (keydes)
            content = "error is x "+file
            s3.Bucket('consumsclients').put_object(Key=keydes, Body=content)    
            
            keydesfile =  cd+"/proc/files/x5d/"+file
            
            #print ("x/"+key)
            #print ("dest: "+keydesfile)
          
            s3.Object("bucket",keydesfile ).copy_from(CopySource="bucket/"+key)
            s3.Object('bucket', key).delete()#delete the file so the process part doesn't treat it
```

I have tried to use the garbage collector just in case for the variables involved in reading each file. Though the error still appears

```
del filedata
del gzipfile
del obj
del content
gc.collect()
```

```
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-6r3bulia/filescontrol.py", line 241, in <module>
MemoryError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/runscript.py", line 142, in <module>
    raise e_type(e_value).with_traceback(new_stack)
  File "/tmp/glue-python-scripts-6r3bulia/filescontrol.py", line 241, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Comment: The python shell environment is generally small. Its even so if you are using the default DPU count of 0.0625. If you have many libraries and files being downloaded and s3 metadata to be kept in memory there is a likely chance of hitting memory issues. Have you tried the 1DPU?

Comment: yes, I have tried with 1DPU. When I do the resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_SELF).ru_maxrss, the values go increasing as iterations take place until around 2895596, which is more or less 2,9GB of RAM. I find it wierd, as 1DPU is said to be 16GB or available RAM. If I use eprint (struct.calcsize("P") * 8) I geet 64, which are teh 64 bits of python version... how could I have more control of memory in Glue?